# What is the naming convention for typeclasses in Scala?

Tags: scala, haskell, naming-conventions, typeclass

In Java world, the naming conventions for interfaces are pretty much well established. For instance, when you say certain class implements the interface `Comparable`, you can say that it's objects are comparable. However the naming conventions for typeclasses are not so well established. For example, `Int` has a `Numeric` implicit available, so you can say "`Int` is a `Numeric` type". But then there is typeclass `Ordering`. I fail to see why this name was chosen. "`Int` is an `Ordering` type" doesn't make any sense. Perhaps it is supposed to be read as "`Int` type has an `Ordering`". Then there are `Equal` and `Show` in Scalaz. I totally have no idea why these names were chosen (apart from that they are so in Haskell.) I tried looking at Haskell, the mother language of typeclasses, for a good naming convention but found that there doesn't really exist any. Haskell guys don't really seem to care about names (That's what I gathered from the mailing list discussions). But coming from Java world, I do care about names. I am not quite able to get accustomed to "types say it all" paradigm.

The question is: What naming conventions do you follow, if at all you do, for naming the typeclasses?

Answer (score 26):

Actually, things are mostly straightforward in Haskell: Type classes are typically named based on what the *operations* represent, not what the *type parameter* represents.

For example:

- `Read`, `Show`: Classes of types for which standard string serialization/deserialization functions are defined.
- `Eq`, `Ord`: Classes of types on which equality and ordering relations, respectively, are defined.
- `Enum`: The class of types defining a "successor" operation, i.e., whose values can be enumerated.
- `Monoid`, `Functor`, `Monad`: Classes of types which define the operations associated with the similarly-named mathematical structures.

Some examples aren't so good: For instance, `Num` is a class of types on which an ad-hoc collection of vaguely-arithmetic-oriented operations are defined, but there's no reason that an instance of `Num` must actually be a *number* in any conventional sense. This could perhaps be handwaved as "types supporting numeric operations", pretending that "numeric" actually means anything in that phrase.

In short, `Numeric` is probably a bad example to imitate, and if a type class has only one function (possibly with multiple variants  on it), it's almost always safe to name the class after that function, as with `show` vs. `Show`.

But really, the main thing is to think in terms of the functions on the type class, not the type parameter. Think *verbs*, not *nouns*. Nouns are dumb inert things anyway, so thinking in terms of actions and operations is likely to lead to better program design.

Comment: Well said. In the object-oriented world, the naming conventions focus on objects (and the associated "is a" relationships). In the function-oriented world, naming conventions focus on functions (which are more like "has" relationships. This data type *has* monad operations. This data type *has* ordering operations).

Comment: @Dan Burton: The really sad part is that, while talking of "things" makes plenty of sense with algebraic data types, *objects* are inherently higher-order beasts and most naturally express active behaviors. In Haskell, data-oriented designs that avoid abstracting over functions are merely a bit clumsy and overly rigid; data-oriented designs in an OOP language are actively toxic.

Comment: On the name/verb dichotomy, Steve Yegge's ["Execution in the Kingdom of Nouns"](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html) comes to mind.