# Why is a "type class" called "type class"?

Tags: scala, haskell, typeclass

When diving deeper into Scala I hit the term **type class**.
 It had been confusing because a class is a type and a type could
 be a class in Scala and "type" and "class" are in itself abstract terms.

After reading some examples I got a feeling what a type class could
 be, but maybe there is an easier approach to get a mental hook
 (picture, concept)  to what a type class is by explaining why it had
 been named like that.

Comment: i wish i had asked that same question when i first encountered them. both answers below would've made my life easier

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Haskell there are no classes in Java/Scala sense, so this term was free to be used (in the sense "class of types", as Johannes Weiß says).

It isn't used in official Scala documentation, but people coming from Haskell found they could emulate Haskell type classes in Scala and reused the name.

Comment: Thank you, now this [answer to a type class naming convention in scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084090/naming-convention-for-typeclasses-in-scala/7084305#7084305) makes much more sense :-)

Comment: Furthermore, "class of types" is using the term roughly in [this sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(set_theory%29). In fact, GHC's `UndecidableInstances` extension makes it very possible to encode *proper* classes, and then proceed to, er, treat them like sets.

Answer (score 17):

Because it classes (together) types "having" a common set operations defined by the type class?

It feels very natural to me.